# Why would a C# instance constructor have a different name from the returned type?

Tags: c#, constructor, instantiation

I sometimes see in C# code:

An instance being created, that then invokes a constructor that is not the same as that of the type.

For example:

```
Person somebody = new Member();
```

What possible cases would this show up in, and why is it desirable?

(I thought it had to do with calling a base class constructor but I couldn't get that to compile)

Comment: Member is child class of Person. Person might have been abstract.

Comment: It's similar to `object o = new String();`, or more intuitively, `Animal fido = new Dog();`

Comment: @Sunny: classes can be abstract? I through only members could be so that they have to be expressly overriden. An abstract class sounds a lot like an interface to me.

Comment: An abstract class and an interface are similar, the difference being the former contains functionality that all child implementations share. For example, an abstract base class may provide an (implemented) method that pulls specific files from the file system, but each child class is required to implement a method that parses those files.

Comment: Your question expresses a few misconceptions. `Person somebody` does not create anything except a variable. A constructor always returns an instance of its type (or results in an exception). The answers explain how a value of one type is assignable to a variable of another type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member inherits from Person or Person is a poorly named Interface and Member implements it:

More on inheritance:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173149(v=vs.80).aspx
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)

More on interfaces:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(object-oriented_programming)

You could define the following using inheritance:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public class Adult : Person
{
    public string Workplace { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Person
{
    public List<string> Toys { get; set; }
}
```

And then if you create an instance of Adult (`Adult a = new Adult();`) you will have access to the Name, DateOfBirth and Workplace properties. Likewise with the child, you will have the Toys property.

Furthermore, you can store a list of Person which contains both adults and children:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(new Adult() { Name = "Adult", DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now, Workplace = "Microsoft" });
people.Add(new Child() { Name = "Child", DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now, Toys = new List<string> { "Car", "Train" } });
```

and then you can go through each printing out the name and date of birth:

```
foreach(Person p in people)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name + ", " + p.DateOfBirth.ToString("dd/MMM/yy"));
    if(p is Child)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name + " has the following toys: " + string.Join(", ", ((Child)p).Toys));
    }
    else if(p is Adult)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name + " works at " + ((Adult)p).Workplace;
    }
}
```

Interfaces basically define a contract (i.e. an object that implements `IPerson` will provide implementations for its methods). It's like an ethernet card: there is a standard for how they talk to the network but how they work internally is up to the manufacturer as long as they provide the expected behaviour. Interfaces can't have any logic in them or store any data, they simply advertise what something implementing that interface provides.

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public class Adult : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Workplace { get; set; }
}

public class Child : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public List<string> Toys { get; set; }
}
```

There's also abstract classes which provide some of the functionality of interfaces but can implement some logic. The only thing to note in all of this is that a class can only be derived from (i.e. inherit from) a single class, although that class can inherit from another class. You can, however, implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: So, using your example, Child someOne = new Person() is pointless because of course the child is a person and inherits those attributes and the Person() constructor probably would be too general anyhow and that's why Person someOne = new Child() makes more sense; because we're saying "here's a person, and lets now specify that its a child, through the Child() constructor. If that's the case, then why not just do Child someOne = new Child() ?

Comment: BTW, thanks for your in depth example. I'll have to parse through the 'beyond the basics' aspects over time.

Comment: @StevenNikolic You can't do `Child someOne = new Person()`, only `Person someOne = new Child()`. Think of it as using an improved version of Person. It's obviously useful from the point of view of shared functionality but it can also be useful for storing things, etc.

Comment: When choosing to create an abstract class or an interface, I generally follow these guidelines: A class 'is a' thing. So if you have a 'Person' base class, a 'Client' is a type of person. An interface on the other hand 'does' something. Suppose you have the following types of 'Persons': developer, tester, manager, director, and vice president. Developer and tester might both perform the 'IWriteCode' stuff, whereas manager, director, and vice president perform an 'ISubmitBudget' set of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This is valid if `Person` is a Base class of `Member`

Similarly this is valid also:

```
Object o = new Member();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really a question about constructors. It is all about **implicit conversions**. In your declaration:

```
Person somebody = new Member();
```

the right-hand side of the `=` operator clearly has (compile-time) type `Member`. However the variable `somebody` has (compile-time) type `Person`. That is legal only if there exists an implicit conversion from `Member` to `Person`. Then the code is really like `Person somebody = (Person)(new Member());` except that the "cast" is invisible.

Now, the most usual implicit conversion is the *reference* conversion from a `class` to its (direct or indirect) base class, or to an interface that it implements.

There is a somewhat different implicit conversion, a *boxing* conversion from a `struct` or `enum` to its base class or interface.

There are also user-defined implicit conversions which are like a kind of methods (written with `implicit operator`).

There are more implicit conversions, for example from a value type `V` to the `Nullable<>` version of it, usually written as `V?`, but it would be strange if `Person` was just a `using` alias for `Member?`, so this one is not realistic in your example. Another one that is rarely relevat in this example, is "widening" conversion from e.g. `int` to `long`.

Read the C# Language Specification to learn more about what conversions exist.

Answer (score 0):

`Member` class probably looks like this...

```
public class Member : Person {}
```

Where `Member` derives from `Person`.